# Selenium webdriver unable to find this one particular element

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I tried looking around for a solution, but haven't found any. Webdriver is unable to find this one particular element for some reason.

Here's the html code:

```
<div id=​"cboxOverlay" style="opacity: 1; cursor: auto; display: none;">​</div>​
```

And I am using xpath to find this element

```
By.xpath("//div[@id = 'cboxOverlay' and contains(@style, 'display: none;')]")
```

When I use firefinder, I can find this element. But it times out and doesnt find the element when I run the code

```
WebElement cboxOverlayWebElement = driver.findElement(cboxOverlay);
```

I have also tried using explicit wait to wait till the element is clickable or visible. Also I am using Java.

Could someone help me? Thanks!!

Comment: I think you'd be good with only `@id` check: `By.xpath("//div[@id='cboxOverlay']")`.

Comment: Is the element inside of a `frame` or `iframe`?

Comment: My understanding is pretty limited, but I've sometimes had a hard time getting WebDriver to find elements properly when there is white space in my XPath. As alecxe suggested, using just the ID--if there are more than one element with the same id, you can tell it which one you want by adding the number in brackets like this: `By.xpath("//div[@id = 'cboxOverlay'][2]")` if it is the second occurrence. If, as Richard suggested, your element is inside a frame, you would need to switch focus to that frame first.

Answer (score 0):

@Sweta

In your html code there is "display: none" means cboxoverlay would not be display. So webdriver also did not get it. Try to fine out what action makes this overlay display and then according write your code.